# Can I go to the end in Minecraft pe

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have had Minecraft for a long time and want to go to the end.  I've tried to make the end portal but it won't  work. Is it that you can only go there on the computer?

Comment: No, Pocket Edition doesn't include the End right now. However, MCPE is still being developed. They might add it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

No,you cannot go to the End. On the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/minecraft-pocket-edition),there are both metioned the lack of other dimensions and infunctionality of the End Portal Frame block.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot.

You can't even go to the Nether anyways on Minecraft PE. The only world you can be is the first world you spawn in. If you go below 64 blocks, you fall into the Void and effortlessly die and lose everything you had on you. Again, no End world.

To be able to access the End, you need to download the full version of Minecraft and access all three worlds then.